# Fullcalendar.io displays some events as a thin vertical line

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.io in my project, and although it's working great, there are some corner cases that makes the events display strangely. This is from an real life example in our project where there are drawn in a lot of parallell events:

[image]

You see here that on day number 2 from the left, three events are displayed as thin lines. If I change the calendar to day view, it look like this:

[image]

So we see those three events are pushed out to the right hand side even if they could have used more of the available space here.

I guess this might be a problem with the algorithm of how fullcalendar.io draws up the events, but have anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution for it?

Comment: It could just be the sheer number of events being unable to fit into the width of the calendar. You could try increasing the overall width, or using custom views to have less days in the view. But also, have you done any customisation of the CSS, even just by adding a theme? Try using the default CSS first and see if you still have the issue

Comment: I have some custom CSS and an override to eventRender. Tried to remove all of that now, but still the same result.

Comment: Ok well next you need to consider my other two suggestions, if that's feasible. Btw which version of fullCalendar are you using? We haven't got any code or suitable tags to inform us. I mention it because if you're using the latest version you may want to consider whether you think it's worth a bug report, having ruled out any influences from your own environment